# counting duplication in a listbox and displaying the number of duplication's

Tags: vba, excel

I have a listbox which is populated by me adding equipment to it, the listbox is allowed to have duplication when it comes to equipment as I may need 2 pieces of the same equipment to complete the job. when the listbox has been filled with the desired equipment I loop through the contents and put them into their cells, however if there is two pieces of the same equipment I want to only list it once but have a number in the cell to the left of it to represent how many of that particular equipment I need.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1).Value = "Number of pieces of equipment"
```

So I need a hand to loop through the listbox to check for duplication and list out the equipment plus the numbers associated with the equipment.

Comment: `So I need a hand to loop through...` Sure we will give you a hand. What have you tried so far to understand and solve the problem? Have you tried any code? If yes, can you show us that and also mention where are you stuck... If No, then why not?

Comment: I told you what I need to loop through in the question. I have it taking all the values in the listbox and putting them into the cells but it displays the values twice if they are in the listbox twice. Thanks for voting the question down as well, NOT

Comment: So what have you tried so far? SO isn't a free code writing service so edit your question with the code you've tried.

Comment: Just telling us what you need is not good enough ;) This is not freelancer.com. You need to show us the efforts that you have put in. I don't see the code that you tried. You have been here for 4 months so you should know how stackoverflow works :)

Comment: As far as the downvote does, improve your question and I will reverse the downvote :)

Comment: "So I need a hand" - I don't feel like that is asking you to provide me with the full code but a nudge in the right direction is what I was looking for!

Comment: I can't give you a nudge till I see what have you tried. I can think of 3 different methods to approach the above problem but I don't want to waste your time and my time suggesting all that :) Instead of arguing with me or with anyone, I would highly recommend that you improve your question. If you don't then you will only invite more downvotes and ultimately this question will be closed. I am ready to help you if you are ready to help yourself... The choice is yours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months of coding I realised that this question had many possible answers! What I decided to do was search the listbox for the element that was going to be added and if that item was already in the listbox the user would get a message telling them of there duplication and the element was not added. If the element wasn't present in the listbox it was added to it and the code below shows how I done this!

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
       myValue = ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i

If ListBox2.ListCount = 0 Then
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem myValue
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.List(i) = myValue Then
        MsgBox "Hardware already selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem myValue
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use VBA.  I would use a pivot table to count occurrences, then use =getpivotdata to populate the counts in the desired location.